# Runing alias or function in background

Tags: bash, linux-mint, alias, background-process

I am connecting to an OpenVPN server from my Linux Mint 19.1 machine. As the Network manager is not setting up routes properly is one uses the GUI to connect I connect by executing:

```
sudo openvpn --config <config-file.ovpn> &
```

To make things easier I have stored all my VPN settings in a hidden folder using a specific tree structure. I wanted to define an alias or a function that executes the above command with a particular VPN setting, that I can call from anywhere.
I've added the following to my .bashrc

```
alias OpenVPN='read -p "VPN name: " VPN_NAME
my_path=~/.openvpn.confs/${VPN_NAME}/OpenVPN
VPN_CONF=${my_path}/vpnconfig.ovpn
sudo openvpn --config $VPN_CONF'
```

This works well but I have to keep the terminal open as it runs in *interactive* mode. I wanted to have it spin up and run in the background so I added a "&" to the last command, which works fine if I call that command manually from the terminal. `sudo openvpn --config $VPN_CONF &` But when I add it to the alias, the system still thinks it is running continuously in the background, but the connection does not work.
I also tried running it as a function, which does not connect either.

```
OVPN() { sudo openvpn ~/.openvpn.confs/"$@"/OpenVPN/vpnconfig.ovpn & }
```

Any suggestions for how this might be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing [this answer about sudo in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26109942/11696639) and doing some trial and error, I have solved it by verifying the user privileges separately, before executing the command in the background:

```
alias OpenVPN='read -p "VPN name: " VPN_NAME
my_path=~/.openvpn.confs/${VPN_NAME}/OpenVPN
VPN_CONF=${my_path}/vpnconfig.ovpn
sudo -v
sudo openvpn --config $VPN_CONF'
```

Here `sudo -v` stands for *validate*, which means that it validates and updates the user sudo timestamp without running a command. Once this is done the following sudo commands do not prompt for a password as this has already been provided.